# Writing a string to the ouputstream of a socket

Tags: java, string, sockets, outputstream

I am working on a project that adapts server-client architecture. Messages that are transferred between clients and the server are combinations of strings and byte arrays. I need to send the size of the whole message beforehand.

It is trivial to find the byte size of a byte array, however it is not so with strings. Obviously, I can convert those strings into byte arrays (taking encodings into consideration). But, these strings can be long and I don't want to allocate memory for copies of them (e.g. getBytes() allocates a new array).

My question is, what is the most memory efficient way of doing the following?

1. Find byte size of a string (using UTF-8 encoding)
2. Write that size to the output stream
3. Write the string to the output stream

Comment: try DataOutputStream. look the javadoc

Comment: @andy Will I know the size of the string that I'm about to write beforehand?

Comment: How long is "long", and have you actually proved that the space/time required for copying is prohibitive? It may well be feasible to do this using `CharsetEncoder` (and the byte counting part is reasonably straightforward) but I think it's worth trying to prove that the simplest possible approach isn't sufficient before you do anything more complicated.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was previously working on a project that involves parsing of VCF files (> 1GB, DNA-genetics stuff) and had to do a lot of profiling, I became aware of how sloppy the garbage collector operates so I am kind of paranoid around Java since then.

Comment: @mostruash: It's all about choosing your battles. Define your requirements, implement the simplest code possible, test it, and then use more complicated code *if* you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the string character by character. Call `codePointAt()` for each position to get its unicode code-point. Depending on the codepoint you can deduce how many bytes will be needed when encoded in UTF-8:

```
Codepoint range | UTF-8 bytes
-----------------------------
0     - 127     |  1
128   - 2047    |  2
2048  - 65535   |  3
65536 +         |  4
```

But before you do that, you should first validate if this is really necessary. It is quite likely that a String passed to a socket is internally copied to a byte array anyway.

Comment: That is why I have been looking for a way to write the string to some temporary input stream and check how many bytes I wrote, and pass that temporary stream to the socket. If all of these would happen without copying stuff around ... You get the point.

Answer (score 1):

If the size is not a critical issue, use UTF16-BE encoding for strings. In this case the size will be string length * 2.

In this mode you can write Java characters one by one without a need to do additional processing (Unicode high-low surrogates etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can always "break" your message in packets, so you make your calculations and memory allocation for some part of the message, iterate into another part and do that again.